# Web3js Events not working as intended in v4.x

Tags: web3js, events

I have a simple contract with an Event. I am trying to use it in my react component. According to the documentation, it can be done like this :

```
contractStorage.events.NewZombie({ fromBlock: 1 })
      .on("connected", console.log)
      .on("data", console.log)
      .on("changed", console.log)
      .on("error", console.log);
```

When used so,it throws me an error saying like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
```

However, When I modify the code like this it works great,

```
const z = contractStorage.events.NewZombie({ fromBlock: 1 });

z._emitter.on("connected", console.log)
      .on("data", console.log)
      .on("changed", console.log)
      .on("error", console.log);
```

Am I doing anything wrong in following the docs Or is it a bug?